Apps targeting Android 13 (API 33) without AD_ID permission will have their advertising ID reset
I am using the package "react-native-google-mobile-ads": "^11.2.0" in my react native android application.In the application content section of the play console, the necessary definitions for AD_ID have been made. It contains advertising and the Analysis checkbox is selected.Ads are already working in my live version right now. I added ads in the previous version.However, when the new version is released, it gives this error in the play console. The only changes I made were to add "Banner" to a few more screens.
When I compile the release version of the application, I see that the "<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" key is added in the android\app\build\intermediates\bundle_manifest\release\AndroidManifest.xml directory




